# Javascript plotly border radius how to

Tags: javascript, css, plotly

Is there an easy way to create a border radius for a plot in plotly module? I have tried this with no luck...

```
var trace1 = {
    x: time,
    y: scaledData,
    mode: 'lines',
    type: 'scatter'
};

var layout = {
    xaxis: {type: 'date'},
    yaxis: {title: 'Moisture %'},
    width: 320, 
    height: 320, 
    margin: {l: 50, r: 30, b: 50, t: 65, pad: 10},
    paper_bgcolor: '#79ff4d',
    plot_bgcolor: '#c6ffb3',
    borderRadius: '15px',
    title:'Past 24 Hours'
}


return (
    <Plot data={[trace1]}
      layout={layout}
    />
  );
```

I also tried the css method but I think I am doing something wrong here as well. I tried creating a div of same size and position and wrapping the plot in it. Then putting a radius on the div but it is behind my plot so it does me no good. Not sure how to do the css hack but I would accept this answer as well, although more work.

Comment: At this time of writing, `borderRadius` is not a supported property listed on the Plotly reference for the [`layout`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/) structure. If want a rounded border around the entire plot component, I'd suggest you use the `className` prop, then define a CSS class which adds the rounded border (you'll likely need `overflow: hidden` to clip the plot contents).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't try using className in the actual plot tag. I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: Well, after many attemps, still no luck. Can you post a quick example please?

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible to get the element by class name if you are displaying this in an HTML page. In my case the class was `main-svg`. In the javascript on your page use the following:

```
<script>
  var plotDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('main-svg') //class name of plotly main area
  plotDiv[0].style.borderRadius = "15px"; //or however round you want
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question as I had the same problem. I just wrapped the plotly plot div with a div and applied a css class with `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden` as mentioned before. That worked for me.